# How to search for user data and retrieve them from firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, data-retrieval

I am trying to retrieve user data that I stored on firebase database and compare it to an inputed text "trying to login but with another way ;)" but when I search for examples I can't quite understand their methods of retrieving data they don't retrieve specific data but the collection, so any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data you need to do the following:

```
  void getUserData() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value){
      print(value.data);
    });
  }
```

Assuming you are using Firebase authentication as the document id

Comment: assumbtion = true :)

Comment: But How can I get the email or the password after and store it in a const

Comment: `value.data` will contain the email and password, you can do `value.data["email"]` and `value.data[password"]`

Comment: about storing it

Comment: store it to an instance variable and cal setState

Comment: It's Ok now , Sorry false alarm.

Comment: Can I change thw way to search for the document by replacing 'firebase.uid' with any thing else right

Comment: if u have uid as a document id, then you need to use the above in the answer

Comment: what about searching by the username that the user entered, Is it possible?

Comment: Like storing the value of username in a controller and put the controller in firebase.uid

Comment: https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/

Comment: What is a query?

Comment: U seem like a smart guy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "where" function in firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
.where('email', isEqualTo: your_text_controller)
.get()
.then(...);
```